# How do we configure hammerjs pinch in/out speed?

Tags: angularjs, hammer.js, pinchzoom, pinch

I am using hammerjs pinch in/out on my SVG element. Currently on single pinch out it is zooming out the maximum but I would like to configure the speed so that I can restrict the zoom based on my step (e.g. 1 step-20% zoom).

Comment: Can you include your code for handling the pinch event? What property of the pinch event are you using and what aspect of the SVG are you changing? For example, if you're setting the element size to a percent that is 100 times the `scale` property, you could instead set it to a smaller fraction of the scale property.

Comment: I am using svg graph and trying to set the pinchin with dynamically and also want to set min and max range for pinchin. There should not be any fixed width and heigth to be added. Please let me know if you have any sample or work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your pinch event, it will cut the pinch speed in half:

```
this.pinchScale = (event.scale / 2) + 1
```

And reactively in your container:

```
width: `${this.containerWidth * this.pinchScale}px`,
height: `${this.containerHeight * this.pinchScale}px`,
```